# Sympathetic Wounds has no listed duration from my source

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I was reading the spell [sympathetic wounds](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sympathetic-wounds) and the source I was reading it from doesnt list any kind of duration. I cant see the spell costing 250 gold for a cast only to have it last for a single round, so the cost suggests to me that its more of a permanent effect.
Does anyone have a source which says?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in its description it functions as [shield other](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shield-other), giving it a duration of **1 hour/level (Dismissible)**.

Comment: I missed that part, thank you. Its still a little odd that the duration wasnt listed.